# Send data along with safeTransferFrom method to onERC721Received function

Tags: solidity

My goal is to send a `loanDuration` (e.g, 1 days, 2 days) value to my `onERC721Received` function when calling the ERC721 `safeTransferFrom` method.

```
function onERC721Received(
         address,
        address from,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes calldata
    )
        external
        override
        returns(bytes4)
    {
        uint256 loanId = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(address(msg.sender), tokenId)));
        loans[loanId] = Loan({
            _tokenContract: ERC721(msg.sender),
            tokenId: tokenId,
            borrower: from,
            loanValue: 0,
            loanDuration: calldata,
            repayable: false
        });
        lend(from, msg.sender, tokenId);
        return 0x150b7a02;
    }
```

However, when I include `loanDuration: calldata` in my loan struct, I get this error:

`ParserError: Expected primary expression.`

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's because [`calldata`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#data-location) is not an argument name but a Solidity keyword. To read the `loanDuration` from the last argument, you need to give it a name. For instance, `bytes calldata duration`. Then, you need to read, say, `uint256` from `bytes`: `loanDuration: abi.decode(data, (uint256))`. Of course, it depends on how the data encoded in the `data` argument. See [ABI Encoding and Decoding Functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=abi.encode#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions).